# inserting the value in the same list rather than in a new

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
arr = [-1, -1, 0, 1, 1]

for x in arr:
    if x > 0:
        list = []
        list.append(x)
        print(list)
```

The output is:
[1]
[1]
But I want the output as:
[1,1]
I want this to insert every positive value from arr to list.

Comment: define the list (list = [] ) outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

you have to define your list before your `for` loop, otherwise, your list will be assigned with an empty list on each iteration

```
arr = [-1, -1, 0, 1, 1]

my_list = []
for x in arr:
    if x > 0:
        my_list.append(x)
        print(my_list)
```

output:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new empty list in every iteration, as kederrac said, you have to define the list outside the loop.
Also, "list" is a keyword in Python, never name variables as keywords! that's a terrible thing to do, and even if it worked fine now, this practice will bite you eventually some day.
A more elegant way to do your task would be using comprehension:

```py
arr = [-1, -1, 0, 1, 1]
myList = [e for e in arr if e > 0]
```